# How to create xUnit Integration tests for REST API controllers (NET CORE 6)

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, xunit, asp.net-core-6.0

I want to create xUnit test with real database, test my middleware and service. In fact I want to create integration test like Postman, SOAP UI or Browser REST client. But I want check my controller with various parameters. Also I have a lot of controllers and methods in each controllers. Some methods has a lot of parameters and call of one method depends from results of another methods.
Therefore various tools like Postman, SOAP UI and Browser REST client don't useful for me. I want to write all integration tests in my own code.
This is common skeleton of my tests.

```
Imports System
Imports BackendAPI.Model
Imports BackendAPI.Services
Imports BackendAPI.WebApi.Controllers
Imports Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
Imports Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
Imports Microsoft.Extensions.Logging
Imports Xunit

Namespace BackendApiTest

    Public Class VmControllerTest
        Dim UserService As IUserService
        Dim DbContext As ApplicationDbContext
        Dim Logger As ILogger(Of VmController)
        Dim Configuration As IConfiguration
        Dim Cryptor As IAesCryptor
        Dim KVM As KvmController
        Dim HttpContextAccessor As IHttpContextAccessor

        Public Sub New()
            ????
        End Sub

        <Fact>
        Sub BashForEachVmTest()
            Dim VmController As New VmController(UserService, DbContext, Logger, Configuration, Cryptor, KVM, HttpContextAccessor)
            Dim Res1 = VmController.BashForEachVm(New BackendAPI.Vm.VmForEachBashRequest With {
            ....
```

How I can initialize instance of services, DbContext (I use EF), HttpcontextAccessor (I use it to access result of my middlware inject to each request), configuration, logger and other controller (I call one controllers from another and use it as service)?
I want to use to this test all class as possible from real project to be tested and use MOCK minimum as possible. In fact I want to store in my test code various parameters for call controllers and create sequence of calling one method depends from result of another methods.

Answer (score 0):

Currently I making full integration API controllers test with the same code

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Text
Imports Newtonsoft.Json

Module Common
    Public Function GetAdminToken(Request As MyWebClient) As String
        Dim PostPrm = New BackendAPI.Model.AuthenticateRequest With {
            .Username = "Admin",
            .Password = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
            }
        Dim PostData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(PostPrm)
        Dim Response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Request.UploadData("/Users/Authenticate", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(PostData)))
        Dim Ret1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Response)
       Return Ret1("token")
    End Function

    Public Class MyWebClient
        Inherits WebClient

        Protected Overloads Function GetWebRequest(URL As Uri) As WebRequest
            Dim WebRequest = MyBase.GetWebRequest(URL)
            WebRequest.Timeout = Integer.MaxValue
            Return WebRequest
        End Function
    End Class

End Module

Imports System.Text
Imports BackendAPI.Masternode
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
Imports Xunit
Imports Xunit.Abstractions

Public Class XcontrollerTest

     Friend ReadOnly BaseUrl As String = "http://localhost:4000/"
     Friend ReadOnly Request As MyWebClient
     Dim Token As String
     Private ReadOnly Log As ITestOutputHelper

     Public Sub New(_Log As ITestOutputHelper)
        Request = New MyWebClient
        Request.BaseAddress = BaseUrl
        Request.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
        Log = _Log
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch()
    End Sub

    <Fact>
    Sub AddXInfo()
        Dim Token = GetAdminToken(Request)
        Request.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
        Request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer: " & Token)
        Dim PostPrm = New SetUpXNodeRequest With {
                    .toVm = 1,
                    .toUser = 1,
                    .toCoin = 1,
                    .ConfigPath = "/root/.xsncore/xsn.tst",
                    .StatusCommand = "/root/.xsncore/xsn-cli getstakingstatus",
                    .Comment = "tst"
                    }
        Dim JsonSerializer = New JsonSerializer()
        Dim PostData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(PostPrm)
        Dim Response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Request.UploadData("/X/AddXInfo", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(PostData)))
    Log.WriteLine(Response)
    End Sub

    <Fact>
    Sub DelMasternodeInfo()
        Dim Token = GetAdminToken(Request)
        Request.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
        Request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer: " & Token)
        Dim Response = Request.DownloadString("/X/DelXInfo" & $"?MasternodeI{33}")
        Log.WriteLine(Response)
    End Sub

End Class
```

If anybody know better solution, please get it